# JavaScript net.connect() - explicitly set local endpoint IP address

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, plc

I can't find a way to set the `local endpoint` field in the `net.connect()` function. I need to explicitly set the `local endpoint` to a specific IP address.

I am using the `node-ads` library to connect a node process to a PLC device.

In my example:

```
ads.tcpClient = net.connect(
    ads.options.port,
    ads.options.host,
    function () {
      ads.connected = true
      cb.apply(ads.adsClient)
    }
  )
```

The `connect()` function does not offer a parameter for this. The returning `socket` object also does not seem to have a field for the endpoint at all. What am I doing wrong?

The reason for this is that I am connecting to a Beckhoff PLC where the connection requires a differnt host IP address if another connection already exists on the same computer. The problem is mentionend [here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ads)

I know for a fact that it is possible in the Beckhoff-ADS C# implementation, as this code works:

```
 var socket = new AmsSocket(targetip, amsport)
 {
     LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sourceip), 0)
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Solved the issue by doing the following:

- Change your `ads.js` file to set the source IP address explicitly
- It's better to not do this in `node_modules`, but to just copy the `ads.js` file somewhere where it does not get overwritten

Locate in `ads.js`:

```
var connect = function (cb) {
  var ads = this
  ads.tcpClient = net.connect({
    port: ads.options.port,
    host: ads.options.host,
    localAddress: ads.options.sourceIp,   // the part you have to add
  },
```

Pass the `sourceIp` in your `options` for the ADS connection:

```
 public options = {
        host: "192.168.100.1",
        amsNetIdTarget: "192.168.100.1.1.1",
        amsNetIdSource: "192.168.100.105.1.1",
        sourceIp: "192.168.100.105",
    };
```

Connect to your PLC:

```
const client = ads.connect(this.options, () => {
            console.log("Trying to connect.");
            client.readDeviceInfo((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error: " + err);
                }
                console.log("Connection result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                client.end();
            });
        });
```

Simple enough, but unfortunately not supported in node-ADS.